# How do I put mysql server in my hidden icons

Tags: mysql

I have downloaded and installed MySql Server. However, it is not listed in my hidden icons. My Apache is in there.
How do I install it in the hidden icons.
My o/s is Windows 11.
Many Thanks,

I expected the mysql server to be listed in the hidden icons. My Apache installed there. I am enrolled with Udemy and followed their instructions on installing the mysql server. There's installed there. What am I missing?

Comment: on windows you might want to try wamp or xampp instead for an easy management of mysql and more services.